# clonezilla image home directory /home/partimag is not a mounting point to a samba server?

Tags: linux, mount, samba, clone, clonezilla

theI just got clonezilla to try it out and I keep having problems with this specific area. To be aware, I am doing this off of virtualbox and saving the image to be samba physical server, and all of my ip addresses are 192.168.1.x

steps I take

start clonezilla -> clone/restore disk -> samba server -> dhcp use dhcp broadcast -> add my ip 192.168.1.75 (my samba server) -> no domain ->

directory where clonezilla image will be saved to or read -> /images (on my samba server)

when i enter my password, i see clonezilla puts
mounting samba server by
mount -t cifs "//192.168.1.75/images" /home/partimag -o user="ABCDE"

then says /home/partimag is not a mounting point! failed to mount other device as /home/partimag

I am only using my att router as a DHCP, so I just have my samba server connected to a switch from my att router

is there something I need to do?

thanks!

---update----

it seems to work fine when i select ssh server and select 192.168.1.75 as an ssh server. I received no error with /home/partimag so why is this happening when i select samba?